# Bugzilla 4.2.4 - Turning Off LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, bugzilla

I installed Bugzilla 4.2.4. After the install I was asked to create a admin account.
So I put in a email address and a password.  Opened Bugzilla and logged in as Admin.  Went through the admin configuration.  I want to use LDAP to authorize my users.  so I set up the LDAP configuration.

I logged out and when I tried to log back in using my LDAP password. I got the following error:

```
Failed to bind to the LDAP server. The error message was: No such object
Traceback:
    at Bugzilla/Auth/Verify/LDAP.pm line 168
Bugzilla::Auth::Verify::LDAP::_bind_ldap_for_search(...) called atBugzilla/Auth/Verify/LDAP.pm line 60
Bugzilla::Auth::Verify::LDAP::check_credentials(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth/Verify/Stack.pm line 62
Bugzilla::Auth::Verify::Stack::check_credentials(...) called at Bugzilla/Auth.pm line 72
Bugzilla::Auth::login(...) called at Bugzilla.pm line 345
Bugzilla::login(...) called at /www/https/htdocs/bugzilla/index.cgi line 40
```

I might have put a LDAP variable in wrong.  But now I can not get back in to Bugzilla.  I went to ./checksetup and recreated the admin password.  But still Bugzilla is trying to authenticate through LDAP.

How can I tell Bugzilla not to use LDAP authentication so I can log back in and check my LDAP variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `Bugzilla/data/params` file, you can set the value for `'user_verify_class'` back to `DB, LDAP`

Comment: For me, I had to completely remove `LDAP` from the line.